# Async.RunSynchronously() vs Async.StartAsTask().Result

Tags: c#, asynchronous, f#, c#-to-f#

Lets say I had an F# computation to deal with in C# and I wanted to make them run synchronously. What would be the difference underneath the hood between:

```
    public static T RunSync<T>(FSharpAsync<T> computation)
    {
        return FSharpAsync.RunSynchronously(computation,
            timeout: FSharpOption<int>.None,
            cancellationToken: FSharpOption<System.Threading.CancellationToken>.None
            );
    }
```

or

```
    public static T RunSync<T>(FSharpAsync<T> computation)
    {
        return FSharpAsync.StartAsTask(computation,
            taskCreationOptions: FSharpOption<TaskCreationOptions>.None,
            cancellationToken: FSharpOption<System.Threading.CancellationToken>.None
            ).Result;
    }
```

Sorry if this seems like a simple question, I am quite new to async programming!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think they will be essentially the same - as Reed says, the first one queues the work directly while the other one creates a `Task`, but the created `Task` is fairly lightweight object (under the cover, this is almost the same and the task is created using `TaskCompletionSource` - you can [see the code here](https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/2923510da9cd9b27f81aec3696f8906122a95f9d/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/control.fs#L1221)).

If you are in control of the F# library, then my recommendation would be to only expose a method that returns `Task` and hide the F# async - this will make the usage from C# much more convenient and you will avoid all the special F# types (like options). If you have `someWork` function in F#, then I would write:

```
type NiceCSharp = 
  static member SomeWork() =
    Async.StartAsTask(someWork())
  static member SomeWork(cancellationToken) =
    Async.StartAsTask(someWork(), cancellationToken = cancellationToken)
```

On the C# side, you will see a nice overloaded method that returns `Task` and works well with `await`. Of course, you can just await the result synchronously using `Result`, but the overhead is not too big - and the fact that you're exposing nice C# API will make it easier to integrate F# in your system.